# Exhibiting the homeomorphism between a torus with a cross cap and a sphere with three cross caps

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading Fraleigh's "A First Course in Abstract Algebra." There's a discussion of how to completely characterize all nice closed 2d surfaces up to homeomorphism on page 182:

> It can be shown that every sufficiently nice closed surface, namely a
> closed 2-manifold, is homeomorphic to a 2-sphere with some number
> $h\geq0$ of handles if the surface is two-sided, and is homeomorphic
> to a 2-sphere with $q>0$ cross caps if it is one sided. The number $h$
> or $q$, as the case may be, is the genus of the surface.

I'm trying to fully understand the consequences of this statement. In particular, I want to consider the torus with one cross cap. According to a mix of calculations done in the book and by myself, I have that the homology groups of this one-sided surface is
$$H_0 = \mathbb{Z},\,\, H_1 = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2,\,\, H_2 = 0$$
which match the homology groups of the sphere with three cross caps.

Assuming my calculation is correct, the quote above seems to imply there must be a homeomorphism between the torus with a single cross cap and the sphere with three cross caps. However, I'm having a difficult time imagining what this homeomorphism would look like - in particular, I'm not sure where the regions surrounding the *three* cross caps of the sphere would map to on the torus with *one* cross cap.

Is my interpretation of the quote (and my homology groups of the surfaces) correct? If so, how should I visualize or construct the homeomorphism between these two surfaces?